# Understanding あんなの見に行ったの

Tags: translation

From the first episode of Death Note:

> マジで？ あんなの見に行ったの？

**Questions:**

1. I know that "あんな" (labeled as a "pre-noun adjective" in my dictionary) means "that sort of thing". Grammatically, is this word just あん + な (where あん is a な-adjective, and the な is just being appended to it to allow it to modify a noun)?
2. Is the の after あんな "nominalizing" あんな?
3. Is 見に行った seen as a single word, or is it (見 + に) + 行った? If the latter, does adding に to verbs transform to the infinitive form? So for example does 見に mean "to see", in this context (so that the whole sentence means "You came **to see** that sort of thing"?

Comment: This might help (if your interest is in the etymology): [Origin of こんな, そんな, あんな and どんな](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68289/43676). How the word is used now is a different story.

Comment: This is related for the third point: [What does しに行く mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/95584/43676)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

School-grammatically and according to デジタル大辞泉, [あんな](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%82%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA/#jn-8836) is na-adjective (形容動詞). From the entry (bold added):

> **あんな has two pre-noun forms あんな and あんなな. Usually あんな is used**, but before ので/のに, あんなな is used. E.g., 事態があんななので、どうすることもできない.

So rather than あん+な, it is あんなな with the last な dropped.

---

The [の](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AE/#jn-171157) here is 準体助詞 （[a related question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/93338/how-exactly-are-%E6%BA%96%E4%BD%93%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E-and-%E5%BD%A2%E5%BC%8F%E5%90%8D%E8%A9%9E-different-in-what-regard-and-where-does-%E3%81%AE-stand)）:

> ２ （活用語に付いて）その語を名詞と同じ資格にすることを表す。「読む―が速い」「彼を行かせる―はまずい」「こんな―が欲しい」→

So yes, の is nominalizing あんな.

---

Generally a particle connects to specific forms of verbs (possibly comparable to prepositions connecting to specific cases of nouns in some European languages).

The relevant definition of に is:

> ［格助］名詞、名詞に準じる語、動詞の連用形・連体形などに付く
> ５ 動作・作用の目的を表す。「見舞い―行く」「迎え―行く」

For the particular case, 見 is 連用形, not infinitive form (I assume it to mean stem).

Practically "Verb (連用形) + に行く" means "go to/and V". From foreigners' grammar perspective, 連用形 covers both te-form and masu-form. And the form that comes before に行く is masu-form. Hopefully someone corrects me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.   If  あんな is na-adjective, then wouldn't it require an additional な before the noun that follows it? Also, is there any difference between a "pre-noun" and a "な-adjective"?

Comment: @sundower So  あんな is not a こそあど言葉 in this sentence?

Comment: @George The quote (I bolded it) from the dictionary should answer your question. It is an exception.

Comment: @ChristelleAugustin You ask it because it is not a pronoun? Then, こそあど言葉 is not a grammatical category, not restricted to pronouns. ([a source](https://content-kessaku.jp/news/kosoado-word/) )